# Can't seem to get int to string converted and to run my program so it outputs 330

Tags: java

I got some homework debugging and I can't seem to get the code to run... new to java and would appreciate any feedback

```
public class Errors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to my first program!\n");

        String ageStr = "24 years";

        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);

        System.out.println("I'm " + age + " years old.");

        int three = "3";
        int threeToString = Integer.parseInt(three);

        int answerYears = age + three;

        System.out.println("Toal number of years: " + answerYears);

        int answerMonths = answerYears * 12;

        System.out.println("In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be " + answerMonths + " months old");

        // Once you've corrected all the errors, the answer should be 330.
    }

}
```

Comment: change `String ageStr = "24 years";` to `String ageStr = "24";` , `int three = "3"` to `String three = "3"; ` , `int answerYears = age + three;` to `int answerYears = age + threeToString ;` That should compile, but i strongly suggest you putting time in learning these basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few errors but I solved it and here's the answer. Pretty basic stuff. I hope you get it.

```
public class Errors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to my first program!\n");

        String ageStr = "24";                           //24years is wrong input, enter only 24

        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);

        System.out.println("I'm " + age + " years old.");

        String three = "3";
        int ageToString = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
        int threeToString = Integer.parseInt(three);
        int answerYears = ageToString + threeToString;

        System.out.println("Toal number of years: " + answerYears);

        int answerMonths = answerYears * 12 + 6;                //you forgot to add 6 months

        System.out.println("In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be " + answerMonths + " months old");

        // Once you've corrected all the errors, the answer should be 330.
    }

}
```